# How to use Foreground Service in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin

Can anyone please help. Am a noob to Android studio. My first major app, is a streaming media player. Problem, i wish to use foreground service, but i just cannot understand how to implement foreground service. I tried searching youtube, but not much on kotlin, and the same with the sites. Can anyone please give me a step by step guide for this.
This is my MainActivity below. The app is working, just missing the foreground service.

```
package com.example.al_bunyan

import android.app.Dialog
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Color
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable
import android.media.MediaPlayer
import android.net.Uri
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.RelativeLayout
import android.widget.VideoView
import java.time.Instant

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        var web_btn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.link_btn)



        web_btn.setOnClickListener {


            var intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, AlbunyaWebview::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        

    }

    fun video_check(view:View) {

        val fm105 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.fm105_7)
        val alert = Dialog(this@MainActivity) 
        alert.setContentView(R.layout.audio_play) 
        val video = alert.findViewById<VideoView>(R.id.video_alert)
        val play = alert.findViewById<Button>(R.id.play)
        val pause = alert.findViewById<Button>(R.id.pause)
        val resume = alert.findViewById<Button>(R.id.resume)



        if (fm105.isPressed) {

            val video_1 = Uri.parse("http://albunyan.fm:8000/live")
            video.setVideoURI(video_1)

            alert.show()

            play.setOnClickListener {

                video.start()
            }

            pause.setOnClickListener {

                video.pause()
            }

            resume.setOnClickListener {

                video.start()
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many resources available including code examples.
following are some of them

1. Android developer docs [Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services)
2. Android developer docs [Foreground services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services)
3. Sample Android project on github [LocationUpdatesForegroundService](https://github.com/android/location-samples/tree/master/LocationUpdatesForegroundService)

I suggest first you read some theory from the first two resources and then try to learn from the code in the github project, which clearly shows how you can implement foreground service.

Comment: mightyWOZ thank you for responding to me. Honestly, i looked at that Android docs so much many times, i've lost count, and I've looked at countless other source codes from github, and still i just don't understand it. Please am new to programming, i learn best through step by step explained instructions. And as well there aren't much source codes on Kotlin.